# Приложение React работает быстрее после перезагрузки страницы (Redux dispatch)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Вопрос не конкретный, но общий. 
Есть достаточно большое приложение на react версии 15.5.4(<16). Приложение всю работу делает через API(WCF сервис), то есть никаких больших вычислений не делает, запрос -> ответ.

При создании формы - это таблица с кучей полей, которые при изменении обращаются к апи, также есть поля с автокомплитом - это быстрые и частые обращения к апи.
При создании такой формы(при первом открытии страницы с формой) все работает где-то в 3 раза медленнее, чем если эту страницу обновить в браузере.
После обновления запросы уходят мгновенно.
В чем может быть причина? Уточню, что это все делается через WebpackDevServer.

В приложении несколько разных страниц с формами - на всех проблема одинаковая.

Работает медленно конкретно dispatch, причем все действия, даже самые простые с одним параметром занимают больше 60мс, после обновления страницы скорость значительно увеличивается( ~ 10-20мс)

Comment: Такая проблема весьма спецэфична. Нужно смотреть, куда уходит время на первом запуске и сравнивать с рефрешами. Возможно первый вызов вызывает загрузку приложения, а затем загрузку службы, когда для второго вызова уже все загружено.

Comment: Какого приложения? Я сравнил время запросов к апи - оно одинаковое до рэфрэша и после(по милисекундам +/-). По отображению запросов правда явно видна задержка именно между запросами. К примеру:option-post-put-option-get. Option можно убрать, итого при изменении значения - я получаю сначала обновленный список(результат вношу в redux store), потом делаю запрос на сохранение в базу данных через апи(я разделил чтобы первый зпрос отработал быстрее и результат был получен без сохранения), get запрос уже делаю после сохранения для получения дополнительных данных (у меня для футэра они нужны).

Comment: Такое ощущение , что задержка происходит между отправлением запросов. (запросы делаю при помощи axios)

Comment: Странное поведение - pending висит долго, но время возвращает 23 мс на запрос(по ощущениям все 600-800)

Comment: От браузера не зависит - проверял в разных, возможно это зависит от CORS(я делаю запрос к локалхосту)

Comment: CORS не при чем тут, время тратится на dispatch. Получается что хранилище работает быстрее после перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел причину. И заключалась она в reduxImmutableStateInvariant() в middleware. Без него приложение просто взлетело.

Оговорюсь, что приложение я дописываю после других людей, оттого многие моменты, которые были применены я не исследовал.